# Strange correlation between Azure Iot hub message count and payload size

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm sending messages from a device to my Iot Hub, of 1.8KB and 1.6KB according to the Azure Dashboard. Using the free tier (with the limit of 0.5KB per message), this should be around 4 messages total. But it's counting as 10 in the application. [dashboard-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgOTo.jpg)

In the dashboard image, the total data usage comes to 127.2 KB, which should be around 255 messages (127.2 KB / 0.5 KB). But according to the system, that is around 715 messages. I also measured the message size in the device, transforming it to a buffer and reading the length property (which comes around to 165 bytes) I'm using the node azure-iot sdk.

This is the code on the device that sends the data:

```
let message = new Message(data);
message.properties.add('source', 'node001');
client.sendEvent(message, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('send error: ' + err.toString());
    } else {
        console.log('message sent!');
    }
})
```

and here is the payload:

```
[{
    "RSSI": "255",
    "timestamp": "2019-08-08T15:05:54.468758+00:00",
    "battery": 0.02,
    "temperature": 18.33,
    "value_2": "-",
    "value_1": 4053,
    "MAC": "00158D000287044D"
}]
```

Using this payload and sending the message every five seconds, I expected the hub to be receiving 1152 message per day (even less, considering the payload is around 0.165KB), but it received more than 8000.

Answer (score 1):

What Encoding you are using ( By any chance is it UTF32). Size of messages differs generally while using  ASCII and Unicode .Could you please post full code. I just tested with C# and Azure Hub reports the same what I am transmitting  and it correlates with what I see in LogAnalytics.